# Multichannel adc with dma values are not exact

Tags: stm32, return-value, zero, dma, adc

I use multichannel(7 channels) adc1 in circular an scan mode with dma.i use ll functions and read adc values in dma_stream_IRQHandler function.the values are not exact and stable.adc sample clock is 14Mhz and I use 84cycles per channel sample.
I use stm32f407vgt IC and keiluvision

I want to the adx values should be correct and stable.because when I connect adc input to ground it is not exact 0 it is like this
8
9
15
20
5

Comment: Did you calibrate the ADC? Which exact STM32 part are you using?

Comment: No.i cant use.because this is hasn't any library for LL_ADC_StartCalibration() function.

Comment: STM has published an entire application note about it: [AN2834: How to get the best ADC accuracy in STM32 microcontrollers](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2834-how-to-get-the-best-adc-accuracy-in-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf). Hint: It's mainly an electrical issue, i.e. precise reference voltage, low-noise power supply, decoupling of VDDA.

Comment: IC is stm32f407vgt

Comment: I read it.but It couldn't help me

Comment: Can I calibrate stm32f407 adc?

Comment: What is the ll calibration code for it?

Comment: I just had a look at the reference manual, and actually I don't see a way to calibrate the ADC. All the other STM32s I've used in the past could do it, so that is quite strange.

Comment: That's mean is usual my result values?

Comment: Not all STM32 ADC [have calibration](http://www.efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g149.html). Also, 5LSB means 5 bins, i.e. +-5 values around the expected one; however, it's a relatively optimistic value for the 'F4xx which is know to be very noisy (you may be able to achieve it with ADC-while-sleep and extremely quiet VDDA/VREF+). Read AN4073.

Comment: How can I solve it?please help me

Comment: Sorry, I have no magic solution for you. If your hardware is not optimal you can slightly improve it following the guidelines in AN2834. You can slightly improve it by averaging (filtering) but that of course decreases effective sampling rate. Or just use a different STM32 model (it's always good idea to test key properties important for your application, e.g. using a Nucleo board with given STM32), or an external ADC which fits your purpose.